# Upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. Xen now has problems with hvm VMs

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, xen

Problem 1:  pv VMs running Ubuntu Linux would run but not connect through bridging until I added
`net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` to `sysctl.conf` (and rebooted).  Unsure why I now need this but looking at issues with when `sysctl.conf` is run in startup (v. old issue) may provide a clue.

Problem 2 : (bigger issue) hvm VM running Windows 10 now refuses to start :

```
root@ap1:/etc/xen# cat zz.cfg
type = 'hvm'
name = 'win10'
memory = 4196
vcpus = 3
vif = ['bridge=xenbr0']
disk = ['phy:/dev/rootvg/win10-disk,hda,w','file:/backups/MLaptop/Windows10.iso,hdc:cdrom,r']
sdl = 0
vnc = 1
vncconsole = 1
vnclisten = ''
vncpasswd = ''
on_poweroff = 'destroy'
on_reboot   = 'restart'
on_crash    = 'restart'
localtime = 1
root@ap1:/etc/xen#  
root@ap1:/etc/xen# xl create zz.cfg
Parsing config from zz.cfg
libxl: error: libxl_dm.c:2426:device_model_spawn_outcome: Domain 18:domain 18 device model: spawn failed (rc=-3)
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:1563:domcreate_devmodel_started: Domain 18:device model did not start: -3
libxl: error: libxl_dm.c:2541:kill_device_model: Device Model already exited
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:1034:libxl__destroy_domid: Domain 18:Non-existant domain
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:993:domain_destroy_callback: Domain 18:Unable to destroy guest
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:920:domain_destroy_cb: Domain 18:Destruction of domain failed
```

Does anyone have any clues as to why this might be failing now I have upgraded ?

More information :- en.service is not starting properly :

```
root@ap1:/etc/xen# systemctl status xen.service
● xen.service - LSB: Xen daemons
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/xen; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-06-18 18:08:58 BST; 1min 58s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 2378 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/xen start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 19033)
     Memory: 30.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/xen.service
             ├─2460 /usr/lib/xen-4.11/bin/oxenstored --pid-file /var/run/xenstore.pid
             └─2466 /usr/lib/xen-4.11/bin/xenconsoled --pid-file /var/run/xenconsoled.pid

Jun 18 18:08:58 apollo systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Xen daemons...
Jun 18 18:08:58 apollo xen[2378]:  * Starting Xen daemons
Jun 18 18:08:58 apollo xen[2469]: qemu-system-i386: -xen-domid 0: Option not supported for this target
Jun 18 18:08:58 apollo xen[2378]:    ...fail!
Jun 18 18:08:58 apollo systemd[1]: xen.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 18 18:08:58 apollo systemd[1]: xen.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 18 18:08:58 apollo systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Xen daemons.
```

Answer (score 5):

Distribution upgrade log from 18.04 to 20.04 stated that it could not find
version 4.9 of `xen` utils (when it was supposed to be installing 4.11).

I tried removing `xen` and then reinstalling it (from Ubuntu using `apt`), but this
did not resolve the problem. So I removed both `xen` and `qemu`, then re-installed
`xen-hypervisor-amd64`.  This has pulled in a version of `qemu` that now supports
the `-xen-domid` switch on `qemu-system-i386`. `xen-service` now reports running OK
and my windows 10 VM now works as before.

Comment: precisely , you need `qemu-system-x86-xen`